# How do I restore GRUB

Tags: 14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1. GRUB was working fine until I pressed the F10 key to check my BIOS. After startup, Windows boots automatically. I have to separately open the boot menu and load Ubuntu. Even restarting from Ubuntu boots Windows. I want GRUB back.

Comment: I can access ubuntu by pressing F9 after starting the laptop. It opens the boot menu, where I select ubuntu and the grub opens. But it doesn't come on its own like it used to after I turned it on.

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu, grub default menu can be verified and set it as default in three steps.

1. open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and find your menu entry title

   e.g. menuentry `'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-25-generic'`
2. then edit `/etc/default/grub`, set menuentry to `GRUB_DEFAULT`

   Change:

   ```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=*
   ```

   To:

   ```
   GRUB_DEFAULT='Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-25-generic'
   ```
3. rebuild `grub.cfg`

   ```
   grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

Maybe this will help.

Comment: I can't access the grub.cfg file. It shows permission denied. When I do it using sudo, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have dual boot windows/ubuntu but you cant boot into ubuntu? think EasyBCD can help you do that. basically it will fix your boot menu.

1- Download EasyBSD in windows: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml#download

2- start the program and go to BCD Deployment. Choose MBR configuration options and then click [write MBR]. Save it.

3- go to Edit Boot Menu you'll see you windows and ubuntu entry. choose them both. save it and Restart your PC. you'll have two options windows/ubuntu choose which one to boot.

Comment: EasyBCD can't find ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

1/You have dual boot windows/ubuntu but you cant boot into ubuntu? reboot your ubuntu desktop/laptop on your live-cd/live-usb Ubuntu.
This will allow you to start a working Ubuntu system with which you can access your files and make maintenance operations in graphical mode.

2/install boot-repair: in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Comment: I can't access the grub.cfg file. It shows permission denied. When I do it using sudo, nothing happens.

Comment: Hi Rashik what give you this command? grub-install -V

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)

Then install it in a usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.