# Installing Ubuntu in SD memory card

Tags: system-installation, sd-card

I have an old laptop whose hard disk is crashed. So, I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in that laptop.

I made a usb installation drive for Ubuntu which gives me the options for trying Ubuntu without installation also.

Now I tried to install that in 8 GB SD memory card. The space requirement was 6.3 GB. So, the installation was complete except in the last phase it shows that the bootloader (grub2) can't be coptied (fatal error) and eventually it didn't work. When start the laptop it just shows me a blank window with a cursor blinking but the screen didn't move forward for a whole night.

Now could you please help me in solving this issue.

The laptop's bios allows booting from memory card.

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! I think this related post will help you resolve your problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/741931/how-do-i-restore-grub

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I am not suggestion install OS on USB drive or memory card. 
at least there is a big difference between their speed.

If you want to mount an SD Card As a Hard Drive anyway? follow this link
https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-mount-an-sd-card-as-a-hard-drive

If you did mean use it for just booting I think this link will help you.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-cool-ways-sd-memory-cards/

Comment: Thanks Asil. I do mean to install Ubuntu on Memory Card. Speed is not an issue in this case.   I hope you'll understand my case.